# iMac Keylogger and other hacks

Tags: encryption

I have someone hacking my computer, this person lives in my home. I know I have a keylogger and a few other things that are making my computer vulnerable etc. My question is: how do I get rid of the keylogger? I have no cash to pay for antivirus software and even then their stuff is weak so I need to know how to fix this myself and maybe even be able to get info on how to build a lawsuit against this person.

Any terminal commands info, how to document and what to document for proof of this, how to keep my Mac safe with more books that I can do myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It's really hard to answer your question without more details about what kind of keyloggers has infected your system, and I believe it will be hard for you to identify which *program* is the actual keylogger either. We are left with depending on the Anti Virus to identify it.
- You can use the *free* version of **Avast** for Mac OS X found in [this](http://www.avast.com/free-antivirus-mac) page. Run a full scan and come back with the results in different post so we can help you in case you needed any further investigations.

Comment: THe problem is that this person lives with me so I cant do much when im not around. Antivirus is vulnerable unless there is a company that can give me free support when this happens through out the time that i am paying for the software service

Comment: You will need to protect your system by setting a password to it

Comment: Btw my keyboard isnt working properly, i heard this is done through a firmware hack.

Comment: I have a password, but my computer is still vulnerable. My mac address also shows up on my internet server, idk if that also makes my comp vulnerable. Thank you guys for the answers though I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 3):

The problem is: *If you can't physically secure your computer then it's not your computer anymore. If I can use your computer, it's not your computer anymore.*

What I recommend you to do is:

- don't reuse passwords (change every single password you have to something very random)
- format your computer and reinstall OS:X
- enable full disk encryption
- use tamperproof seals to secure your iMac's case

This will make it a lot harder to just break into your machine.

Comment: I'd also add tamperproof seals on the USB (keyboard, mouse, etc) connections to prevent hardware tampering (e.g. hardware keyloggers). But as you say, if the hacker has uncontrolled physical access, you can't really keep them from spying on you, the most you can do is make it a bit harder.